# Making jenkins parallel blocks more comprehensible by humans

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins parallel blocks are great but they do raise the bar for human comprehension as they interleave output.

```
def mysteps = [:]
mysteps['something'] = { sh "do-something.sh" }
if (wantOtherThing) {
   mysteps['otherthing'] = { sh "do-otherthing.sh" }
}
parallel mysteps
```

This executes creating console output like so:

```
[something] ...
[something] ...
[otherthing] ...
[something] ...
...
```

The case above offers a simple option - redirect output to a log file and cat that to the log later.  If I used a series of jenkins plugins & tasks (e.g. ansible-playbook task) then un-interleaving the output is more of a challenge.  In that case the only option seems to be create specific log files and store them as build outputs.

Is there another approach to keeping the console spartan, comprehensible while still maintaining:

- somewhat dynamic console so folks can watch the build
- enough debug information so we can tell why a job failed?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the output in Blue Ocean, it separates the output for each parallel task